# Access macOS High Sierra from a Windows 10 machine using RDP?

Tags: high-sierra, remote-desktop

I wish to use Remote Desktop Protocol on my Windows 10 machine to remotely access my MacBook Air running macOS High Sierra.

Is this possible in any way shape or form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote access over RDP is possible from macOS to Windows but not vice versa.

You can instead configure **Screen Sharing** from within **Sharing** preference pane under **System Preferences** app and connect to the Mac from Windows using one of the many [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) client apps.

[image]

Comment: I guess you meant to say VNC apps?

Comment: Yes. Unlike RDP which is Microsoft's proprietary protocol, VNC is open and available across all major platforms. VNC client app by various vendors are available for all major computing platforms.

Comment: You may want to correct the VLN typo in your post?